# Filter sub documents by sub-sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Imagine, you have the following mongoose schema:

```
mongoose.model('Team', mongoose.Schema(
{
 players : [{ 
    trikots : [{
        isNew : Boolean,
        color : String
    }]
 }]
})
```

I want to query my data to get all teams, that match the following

- have trikots {isNew : true, color : red}
- only select players, that have trikots {isNew : true, color : red}

I started by using $elemMatch for the sub-subdocument, but their still false players. Do I have to use aggregate()? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's quite achievable with **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**. Your aggregation pipeline will consist of a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator which becomes the initial stage. This filters the documents in the collection by the specified criteria. The next pipeline steps will be a couple of [**`$uniwnd`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operators on both arrays, `players` and the nested `players.trikots`. After the [**`$uniwnd`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) , you will need another [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) to then filter the deconstructed array documents down to the required criteria which becomes your final solution.

Let's demonstrate this by inserting a couple of documents with the above schema to the team collection in mongo shell:

```
db.team.insert([
{
    "players" : [ 
        {
            "trikots" : [ 
                {
                    "isNew" : true,
                    "color" : "red"
                }, 
                {
                    "isNew" : true,
                    "color" : "blue"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "trikots" : [ 
                {
                    "isNew" : false,
                    "color" : "red"
                }, 
                {
                    "isNew" : true,
                    "color" : "green"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "players" : [ 
        {
            "trikots" : [ 
                {
                    "isNew" : false,
                    "color" : "red"
                }, 
                {
                    "isNew" : false,
                    "color" : "blue"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
])
```

The above aggregation pipeline can then be implemented as follows:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "players.trikots.isNew": true,
            "players.trikots.color": "red"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$players"
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$players.trikots"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "players.trikots.isNew": true,
            "players.trikots.color": "red"
        }
    }
];
db.team.aggregate(pipeline);
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("554bce9a2ba32ccf7f139bae"),
            "players" : {
                "trikots" : {
                    "isNew" : true,
                    "color" : "red"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Your mongoose aggregation would be similar:

```
Team.aggregate(pipeline).exec(callback);
```

Or using Mongoose **[aggregation pipeline builder](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** for a fluent call:

```
Team.aggregate()
    .match({"players.trikots.isNew": true,"players.trikots.color": "red"})
    .unwind("players")
    .unwind("players.trikots")
    .match({"players.trikots.isNew": true,"players.trikots.color": "red"}) 
    .exec(callback);
```

Comment: Now I get the following Error: "exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'." Any suggestions?

Comment: @FlorianMozart My apologies I gave you untested code, I've updated the answer now so give that a try and let me know.

Comment: One last question: If I have multiple players from one team, which have the requirements. How can I aggregate to get one team object with all these players?

Comment: @FlorianMozart Is it ok if you create a new question for that as I believe it requires a different solution than the above?